# Простое решение в поиске нужного числа из интервала

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день, подскажите плиз ,  максимально простое решение для поиска числа в интервале по  задаче 
есть таблица в БД

```
сумма от   сумма до   процент
 1            200       1,5
 201          400        2
 401          1000       3
```

у меня будет приходить любое число к примеру 300 и мне нужно под это число подставлять процент соответственно из моей таблицы это будет 2%
как можно обойти цыклы или сложные решения ?
эту таблицу можно группировать в массив

Comment: выберите единственную нужную строку в запросе и все.

Comment: @Женя псевдокод: select процент from таблица where 300 >= сумма от and 300 <= сумма до

Comment: забыл уточнить, что обращаться к базе данных мы не будем , запрос планируется закешировать ,у нас будет кешированный массив,  так как большое количество обращений планируется к этой таблице

Comment: *запрос планируется закешировать ,у нас будет кешированный массив* Ну так получи эти данные в массив в сортированном по сумме виде и ищи нужную строку массива половинным делением, скажем, по нижней границе, а потом проверяй по верхней (а ещё лучше - при получении массива проверь его на отсутствие "дыр").

Comment: – Akina -- 
не совсем понял как сделать половинным делением если у нас в таблице нет числа 300 а есть 200 и 400 ?

Comment: а в чем проблема написать цикл то?

Comment: та нет не проблема уже написал , хотел найти оптимальное решение , я понял только циклом

Comment: если у вас данные кэшированы в массив, то решения кроме цикла и не будет. хоть он  там прямой, хоть с делением пополам. если у вас там десяток значений, то простой цикл пока не найдется сумма_от, которая выше искомой, и все.

Comment: @teran, вообще-то бинарный поиск ещё существует.

Comment: @Qwertiy выше вроде написано про деление пополам, к чему коммент?

Comment: *как сделать половинным делением если у нас в таблице нет числа 300 а есть 200 и 400 ?* Искать надо не точное значение, а максимальное не превосходящее (если искать по минимальному) либо минимальное не меньшее (если по максимальному). В стандартном коде МПД просто строгое равенство заменяется на "больше или равно/меньше или равно".

Comment: @teran, да, кажется я половину комментария только прочитал...

Answer (score 1):

```
select MinAmount, MaxAmount, Percent from tbl where @amount between MinAmount and MaxAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Набросал вот такое решение может его можно упростить?

```
public static function getPercent($product_id, $amount = null)
{
    if($amount === null){
        $amount = Yii::$app->user->identity->power;
    }
    if (!$value = Yii::$app->cache->get('product_discounts_percent')){
        $value = array();
        $arr = static::find()->asArray()->all();
        foreach ($arr as $v){
            $value[$v['product_id']][]= [
               'interval_from'=> (int)$v['interval_from'],
                'interval_to' => (int)$v['interval_to'],
                'percent' => (float)$v['percent']
            ];
        }
        Yii::$app->cache->set('product_discounts_percent', $value, self::CACHE_TIME );
    }

    if(!isset($value[$product_id])){
        return self::MINIMUM_AMOUNT_ACCRUAL;
    }

    foreach ($value[$product_id] as $data){
        if($amount >= $data['interval_from'] && $amount <= $data['interval_to'] ){
            return $data['percent'];
        }
    }

    return self::MINIMUM_AMOUNT_ACCRUAL;
}
```

Comment: вы считаете, что не надо было в вопросе указать, что вы используете Yii ?

Comment: да вопрос не в yii, а в способе , я хотел использовать возможно какие-то готовые решения для поиска в промежутке

Comment: если у вас промежутки не перекрываются (что логично, иначе какой брать?), то искать надо последнее значение СуммыОт, которое меньше искомого. цикл в строку.

Comment: а вообще хранить массив скидок для всех продуктов хорошо ли? сколько у вас их всего? имеет ли смысл это кэширование?

Comment: teran--
по поводу последнее значение СуммыОт  -- спасибо подходит 
по поводу кеширования 
-- продуктов не много их может быть до 10 , но пользователей может быть много и каждому пользователю отдать его процент это уже накладно